# How to determine the number of nearby samples for spatial estimation?

Tags: estimation, spatial, interpolation, k-nearest-neighbour

In many applications e.g, in mining engineering when we need to generate a map of dispersion of an element (e.g., copper) over the field of study, to depict depletion and concentration regions we have to apply estimation methods on the existing samples. Samples are dispersed everywhere: some parts appear to be more random and some other parts more regular. In estimation procedures such as IDW (Inverse Distance Weighting) and Kriging and so on we prefer to incorporate a limited number of nearby samples in the estimation of each centered point. If for the discussion we disregard the computing optimizations, **what can be the criteria to choose a right number of samples for estimation?**

**Notes:**

- In mining engineering and geosciences it is a common practice to choose a number of between 10 and 15 samples for the averaging.
- Incorporating more samples generates smoother results which are in some cases the desired outputs but not for all the cases.
- The question seeks a statistical criteria instead of visualization impression which is also commonly referenced as a criteria!

**important note:**
The question appears general. Kriging or IDW are only examples. The criteria sought should be able to be generalized for any estimation method.
*Kriging:* this method due to its basics (matrix solution) requires a small number of samples to be solvable.

Comment: There are good reasons to dispute the first two notes.  It *used to be* common practice to use smallish neighborhoods for kriging irregular data due to the $O(n^3)$ computational demands of the algorithm (where $n$ is the neighborhood size).  That's rarely an issue any more.  With kriging, the *only* reason you get smoother results is because the discontinuities introduced when neighborhood populations change are reduced.  (There's a well-known "screening effect" that can severely limit the leverage of the more distant neighbors.)

Comment: Are you aware that there are [ASTM standards](http://www.astm.org/Standards/D5922.htm) for a geostatistical analysis?  And that they specify particular ways to choose estimation neighborhoods (including jackknifing and other forms of cross-validation)?  Choosing estimation neighborhoods is a standard part of kriging that is described in *any* textbook on the subject.

Comment: The standards (ASTM) are new to me! Thanks for the advice. How about other interpolation methods?

Comment: You might get an answer on the [Geosciences proposal on area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36296/geoscience), if the site gets up. You should go there and commit :D